# Array of numbers to Array of one string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, function, numbers

I need to [1, 2, 3] over to ['123'].
I must return [1, 2, 3] over to ['123'] while using an arrow function (no regex):

Must be used:

---

```
const functionOne = (arrayOne) => {

};

console.log(functionOne([1, 2, 3]));
```

---

So, I tried the following:

First, I created a string. This gave me 1,2,3

Then, I removed the commas, so, I could join the numbers. This gave me 123.

Finally, I tried to put back the number as a string into the array but this didn't work. This gave me `['1', '2', '3']` instead of `['123']`. I think the `.split` method is what is wrong in my code but I cannot find another one (currently learning JavaScript).

```
const functionOne = (arrayOne) => {

  let stepOne = arrayOne.toString(arrayOne => arrayOne.toString());

  console.log(stepOne);

  stepOne = stepOne.split(',').join('');

  console.log(stepOne);

  return stepOne.split('');

};

console.log(functionOne([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: Why are you splitting the joined string? Also, `.toString(arrayOne => arrayOne.toString());` seems redundant. Could you not use `return [arrayOne.join('')]`?

Comment: I joined the string to remove the comma. So, instead of having the sting 1,2,3, I will get the string 123.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) using `""` as the delimiter (it will automatically convert the elements to strings as it produces the output string), then put the result in an array as its only element (`[____]`):

```js
const functionOne = (array) => [array.join("")];
console.log(functionOne([1, 2, 3]));
```

Issues with your original approach:

- Array's `toString` completesly ignores the argument you're giving it, instead using its default behavior of `join(",")`.
- Splitting it on `,` again just gives you back an array, but this time of strings.
- Rejoining that with `join('')` *does* give you `"123"`, but doesn't put it in an array.

Comment: @terpinmd - My impression was the OP wants to create a function to do it (e.g., for reuse). So the first line is doing that. The second is showing how the function is used. But yes, of course you can do it inline as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive function.

```js
const
    fn = ([v, ...rest]) => rest.length
        ? [v + fn(rest)]
        : [v];

console.log(fn([1, 2, 3]));
```

Comment: Yes, but...why *would* you? :-)

Comment: i would never, but i was playing with coercing to string when adding an array.

Comment: Made even more amusing by the fact that it relies on an implicit `join()` call for string coercion

Answer (score -1):

```
const functionOne = (arrayOne) => {
  let stepOne = arrayOne.toString();
  stepOne = stepOne.split(',').join('');
  return [stepOne];
};

console.log(functionOne([1, 2, 3]));
```

The .toString() method will convert the array [1, 2, 3] to the string "1,2,3", then .split(',').join('') removes the commas and joins the numbers as a single string "123". Finally, return [stepOne]; returns the string "123" inside an array ['123'].

Comment: There's no need to create a string, then create another array, *then* create a string again. See the CW answer I posted a few minutes ago, all you need is `[arrayOne.join("")]`.

Comment: There is indeed no need to do all the steps, and your answer/code is way refined, but I tried making the code more understandable (imo) as the op mentioned they are learning javascript.

Comment: Thank you T.J and Sylveon for you your help. I noted that there was no need to go through the steps I initially put in my code. The `[arrayOne.join("")]` allows to directly return [1, 2, 3] to ["123"]. Thanks.

Comment: @sylveon I agree.  Its pretty clear the OP is learning js.  This is just one other option on how to accomplish a task.